# Django manage.py outside of project

Tags: python, django

Is there a method of having `manage.py` outside of the Django project directory without having to change all the imports to `from backend.<app>.<module> import ...`?

```
├── project
│   ├── api
│   ├── frontend
│   ├── project
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── Pipfile
│   ├── Pipfile.lock


├── project
│   ├── backend
│   │   ├── api
│   │   ├── project
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── frontend
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── Pipfile
│   ├── Pipfile.lock
```

As expected after moving the Django project into the backend directory and modifying `manage.py` with the line below there's a `ModuleNotFoundError` when trying to run the server.

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.project.settings')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable `import api` instead of `import backend.api`, you need to add the parent directory `backend` to the python path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/project/backend')
```

You can also use a relative path if `manage.py` is in `/path/to/project/`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('backend')
```

You should then use

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
```

After making the changes, make sure you import `api` everywhere. Mixing `import api` and `import backend.api` can cause problems when the same modules are imported in different places. You can probably remove `backend/__init__.py` if you are going to stop importing `backend`.

Comment: Thanks, this works but `./manage.py test` is broken without `backend/__init__.py`

Comment: If `backend/__init__.py` works for you then keep it. I suggested removing it because I've seen people having issues when there is an `__init__` in Django's root directory but I can't remember the specific details or reason.